# Quitar decimales a campo money sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tengo un problema necesito quitar los decimales de un campo sin perder los
puntos de los miles, la consulta que hago es la siguiente

```
('$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(OTGRMR.[mny_ValorUnitarioRP_GRMR]  AS MONEY),1))) AS VALORUNITARIO
```

y me devuelve DE `1327.96 = $1.327.96`

Pero no necesito los decimales es para un reporte en jasper y el cliente no los quiere ahí

Entonces para quitarlos hago la consulta asi

```
('$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(OTGRMR.[mny_ValorUnitarioRP_GRMR]  AS NUMERIC),0))) AS VALORUNITARIO
```

Y me devuelve de `1327.96 = $1328`
peo pierdo los "." de los miles y el cliente los quiere adicional el reporte se ve mal sin ellos

Como puedo quitar los decimales sin perder los miles, o quitar los decimales manteniendo el campo tipo  money.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: No des formato en SQL Server, deja todo el formato para el front-end.

Comment: y que funcion puedo usar en jasper para quitar los decimales

Comment: [Esto te puede ayudar, 15 segundos en san google](https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tip-custom-pattern-decimal-values-field-jasper-ireport-5x-or-jasper-design-studio-6x-useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es "Truncar" los decimales, pero quitar estos. Hay dos formas de hacerlo y ambas son "peligrosas" por sus propias limitaciones:

- Convertir a `varchar` y truncar la cadena: pierdes la naturaleza numérica del dato
- Redondear truncando los decimales y convirtiendo a `INT`: pierdes la capacidad de soportar números grandes, el máximo es de 2,147,483,647, eventualmente podrías convertir a BIGINT, pero eso seguramente te traerá otros problemas.

Ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Valor MONEY = 1327.96
SELECT  @Valor          'Original',
    CONVERT(INT, ROUND(@Valor,0,1)) 'Truncado a INT',
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Valor*100), LEN(@Valor) - 3) 'Truncado a VARCHAR'


             Original Truncado a INT Truncado a VARCHAR
--------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
              1327,96           1327 1327
```

PD: Como consejo adicional, a menos que sea imposible resolverlo, dejá este trabajo para la capa de visualización

Comment: no, ninguno de esos 3 resultados es el que busco lo que quiero es el numero sin redondear y sin decimales, que no muestre el .00

Comment: @juandavidzambrano,  ok, ahí ajusté mi respuesta, de cualquier forma francamente dudo que te sirva por los problemas varios que genera cada solución. Saludos.